# Runtime error when trying to make a .exe from .py script with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, compiler-errors, kivy, executable, pyinstaller

I'm trying to make a .exe file from a python script that I wrote. The problem is that when I run pyinstaller from the command line it doesn't produce any .exe file in the build directory but instead it returns the error message you can find attached. Within this, aside from all of the many WARNING(s), I think that the most relevant statement with respect to the problem could be the following **RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v12.0 to v12.3 but the PyQt5.QtCore module requires API v12.4**. What I did is first try to perform the task on the original script -which comprehends code for a GUI developed using Kivy- and then switched to a simpler one which you can find below. Please notice that  I'm using Python 3.6 and PyInstaller 3.3.1 and already tried to uninstall and reinstall pyqt5 through pip3 (which solved some other error messages I was getting).  I also made some attempts to do the same task by using cx_Freeze but didn't get any luck (probably due to compatibility reasons with python3.6), but I would be open also to any suggestions regarding the use of other packages. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
import pandas
import numpy as np


df = pandas.read_excel(xlsname)
df.replace(np.nan, 'NaN', inplace = True)      
schema_list = df['Schema/Owner'].unique()
ii = 1
axs_d = open(filename + '.txt','w')
for schema in schema_list:
    ref_val = 'N'
    tables_list = list(df.loc[df['Schema/Owner'] == schema].ix[:,'Nome Tabella'].unique())
    s_table = tables_list[0]
    axs_d.write('CREATE EXTR ' + activity + '.' + ext_name + "\n  DESC //'" + schema + "'//"  +
                "\n  XF //'E:\OptimFiles\XF\\" +  activity + "\\" + activity + "_EXT\\" +  activity +
                "." + ext_name + ".XF'//\n  LOCALAD (\n" + '    SRCQUAL ' + dsalias + '.' + schema +
                    ' START ' + s_table + ' ADDTBLS N MODCRIT N ADCHGS N USENEW Y' +
                    ' USEFM N PNSSTATE N SOLUTION 0\n')
    ii = ii + 1
    for table in tables_list:
        axs_d.write('    TABLE (' + table +
                    ' ACCESS SUID REF ' + ref_val + ' DAA N UR N PREDOP A VARDELIM : COLFLAG N' +
                    '\n      EXTRROWID N )\n')
        ref_val = 'Y'
    axs_d.write('  )\n  PNSOVERRIDE N PNSOPT N\n  ALWAYSPROMPT N OPTION D INCLPK N INCLFK N INCLIDX'
            + ' N INCLALIAS N INCLASSEMBLY N INCLFUNCTION N INCLPACKAGE N INCLPAR_FUNCTION N'
            + ' INCLPAR_SCHEME N\n  INCLPROCEDURE N INCLSEQUENCE N INCLTRIGGER N INCLVIEW N' +
            ' INCLDEFAULT N INCLRULE N INCLUDT N INCLMETHOD N IGNOREUNKNOWN N COMPRESSFILE Y' +
            ' COMPRESSMODEL 1\n  COMPRESSACTIVE N ENCRYPTXF N GENSTATISTIC Y PROCESS_FILEATTACH'
            + ' Y ROWLIMIT 0 DBCONNECTIONS 1 ;\n\n' )
axs_d.close()
df.to_excel(xlsname + "_new.xls",index = False)
```

error messages

[image]

Comment: Please check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
Add your code , what have you tried.

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: And if you run `sip-v` on the command line, what value is returned?

Comment: my bad, I'm on Windows 10. sip-v just returns an error @JaredForth

Comment: @LucaGranalli I posed an answer with a couple possible solutions - let me know if they are effective, otherwise I'll keep on working on it

Comment: @LucaGranalli: I am using Python 3.5 and PyInstaller 3.3.1 without error. Please try downgrading to Python 3.5. Try to compile the Kivy example, touchtracer.

Comment: @JaredForth, I think you mean `sip   -V`, correct?

Comment: @JohnAnderson Yep that’s correct! Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test this solution as I am on Linux and Mac, but the problem could be that the sip module merely needs to be updated. There are two potential fixes I can think of:

1. If sip is installed, `sip-V` shouldn't return an error, so try running `pip3 install SIP`
2. If this does not work, I would try to uninstall PyQt5 with `pip3 uninstall pyqt5` and than install it again with `pip3 install pyqt5`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it seems to be fixing some of the displayed error. Still I can't manage to draw out an executable from pyinstaller. One error that stands out and may be the cause could be the following:
RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v12.0 to v12.3 but the PyQt5.QtCore module requires API v12.4

Answer (score 0):

The Runtime error is fixed by uninstalling and reinstalling both pyqt5  and sip. In the end, fixing such error allows pyinstaller to regularly produce the wanted .exe file from the chosen python script.